# Can't copy nuget file into destination when I use MSBuild Property Functions

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, csproj, msbuild-4.0

I have two goals on my current task; increment the *version number* of a Nuget package version automatically, and *copy* the generated **.nupkg** file into a new folder after the build.

With `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` inside my **.csproj** file I am trying to use a dynamic method (*MSBuild Property Functions*) to increase the version number of my assembly version. Instead of static definition `<version>1.0.0</version>` I am able to create something dynamic like this; `<version>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd"))</version>`. This creates a file named **projectName.2017.7.26.nupkg** inside the bin/debug folder.

This process generates a file but it causes an synchronization issue in msbuild build process. On the second step, when I try to copy the file to the destination, I get the error: **Could not copy the file "bin\Debug\projectName.2017.07.26.nupkg" because it was not found**

Half a second after this error shows up, the Nuget package file appears in the bin\debug folder with the same name.

If I don't use `$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd"))` but use a static version number like `1.0.101`, everything works fine and the file gets copied to the destination folder.

This is the relevant parts from my csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <NewVersionNumber>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd"))</NewVersionNumber>
    <CopyDestionationPath>..\Nuget</CopyDestionationPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.0;net46;net40</TargetFrameworks>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageId>$(AssemblyName)</PackageId>
    <version>$(NewVersionNumber)</version>
    <title>A Package</title>
    .....
</PropertyGroup>
.....
<Target Name="CopyPackage"  AfterTargets="Pack">
    <ItemGroup>
      <OldNugetFiles Include="$(CopyDestionationPath)\*nupkg" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <NewNugetFile Include="$(OutputPath)$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Delete Files="@(OldNugetFiles)" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(NewNugetFile)" DestinationFolder="$(CopyDestionationPath)"/>
</Target>
```

Do I need something else in **AfterTargets** of CopyPackage task, currently it's set to pre-defined target of Pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem is that leading zeros will be cut from the version numbers. So for example if `PackageVersion` is `2017.07.27`, then the resulting file will be called `projectName.2017.7.27.nupkg` but you are specifically looking for one with an extra `0` in there - which really does not exist.

If you use

```
<NewVersionNumber>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy.M.d"))</NewVersionNumber>
```

your code should work.

Comment: Yes this is correct, thank you! I've got lucky and found that it was to do with the formatting moments before I left work yesterday, I tried this and worked then figured it has something to do with formatting. '<Days>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("dd"))</Days>
    <NewVersionNumber>$([System.string]::Concat("1.0.0.", $(Days)))</NewVersionNumber>'. I know exactly why thanks to your explanation now.